# (unsigned __int16 to float) and float to (unsigned __int16) typecast vs union in C++

Tags: c++, casting, unions

I have 3000 floating type(4 byte) variables and 2000 unsigned __int16(2 byte) variables. These variables stores data from plc.

I have a constant struct array which stores the information of each plc tag.

```
struct  strPLCtags
{
    unsigned short   id ;           //plc tag id        
    unsigned __int16 mbaddress ;    //plc Modbus address    
    String           name ;         //plc tag name  
    String           description ;  //plc tag description   
    Byte             datatype  ;    // 2 = ushort ; 4 = float  
    Byte             plcaccess   ;  //Read, Write, Read/Write Tag
};

const strPLCtags  plcTags[5000] = {{....},{....},.................,{....}};
```

I want to group all of the above variables(3000 float + 2000 ushort) as a single array[5000]. So, I can access value of plc tag based on tag index.

I came up with two solutions. But not sure which one is correct to use.

**Solution 1:**  declare float array[5000] and access value based on plc tag id.

```
  float   PLCDataArray1[5000] ;

  //Get PLC data and assign to array

  PLCDataArray1[0]    = static_cast<float>(GetU16ValueFromPLC(addr)) ;
  PLCDataArray1[1]    = GetFloatValueFromPLC(addr) ;
  .
  .
  PLCDataArray1[4999] = GetFloatValueFromPLC(addr) ;

 //To read back above data as String and show it on form.
 String GetPLCData(unsigned short tid) //tid is plc tag id
 {
     if(plcTags[tid] == 2)
     {
         return IntToStr(PLCDataArray1[tid]) ;
     }
     else
     {
         return FloatToStrF(PLCDataArray1[tid],ffFixed,6,2) ; 
     }
 }
```

**Solution 2:**

```
union uFltOrUS16
{
    unsigned __int16 usVal;
    float            fltVal;
};
uFltOrUS16    PLCDataArray2[5000] ;

//Get PLC data and assign to array
  PLCDataArray2[0].usVal     = GetU16ValueFromPLC(addr) ;
  PLCDataArray2[1].fltVal    = GetFloatValueFromPLC(addr) ;
  .
  .
  PLCDataArray2[4999].fltVal = GetFloatValueFromPLC(addr) ;

 //To read back above data as String and show it on form.
 String GetPLCData(unsigned short tid) //tid is plc tag id
 {
     if(plcTags[tid] == 2)
     {
         return IntToStr(PLCDataArray2[tid].usval) ;
     }
     else
     {
         return FloatToStrF(PLCDataArray2[tid].fltval,ffFixed,6,2) ; 
     }
 }
```

Could you please suggest me which type of above solution is better to use for my problem?
If both of above aren't good to use, please suggest me a better idea to implement.

Thank you.

Comment: Reading a member of a union other than the last written one is Undefined Behaviour.  memcpy is the best way to move bytes into a different representation, just take care with alignment.

Comment: @Richard Critten : Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're attempting to do with the `union` is called [Type Punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning), and is undefined behavior in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11996970/2642059

Because unions are frequently abused *because* of the speed afforded by `union` based Type Punning so most C++ compilers *do* support such behavior.

In short if you intend to write portable [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) which conforms to the standard, you'll need to use **Solution 1**; however depending upon your compiler, you may find **Solution 2** to be a faster solution on your compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the link and I decided to follow user suggestion.